# How to understand "hadoop is good for sequential data access"

Tags: hadoop

I tried to compare the performance about write a big file between local filesystem and HDFS. The result is sort of makes me confused. Time elapsed through write local is shorter than HDFS. I don't understand the concept "Hadoop is good for sequential data access"...

```
[root@datanodetest01 tmp]# dd if=/dev/zero of=testfile count=1 bs=256M
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
268435456 bytes (268 MB) copied, 0.324765 s, 827 MB/s

[root@datanodetest01 tmp]# time hadoop fs -put testfile /tmp

real    0m3.461s
user    0m6.829s
sys     0m0.666s
```

Comment: it seems you are comparing a local filesystem with a distributed one, how do you account for the replication that needs to be done on a distributed filesystem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HDFS comes with plethora of benefit, which is listed [here](http://www.itproportal.com/2013/12/20/big-data-5-major-advantages-of-hadoop/) and [here](http://www.j2eebrain.com/java-J2ee-hadoop-advantages-and-disadvantages.html)

Please note that whether you store the data within local disk or on HDFS, ultimately you would like to dome some processing on the data. In that case, all the Big data technology stack leverage upon HDFS characteristic to provide a fast processing of data in a fault tolerant manner.

The difference in copying a data within local vs hdfs can simply be attributed to below facts:

1) HDFS makes at least 3 copies of data, so that it works into Highly available manner, no matter whether a machine is cluster goes kaput.

2) In HDFS, the data copies are maintained on different machine across cluster, hence some network I/O takes place.

Also note that - ref http://hadooptutorials.co.in/tutorials/hadoop/hadoop-fundamentals.html

Hadoop uses blocks to store a file or parts of a file.
A Hadoop block is a file on the underlying filesystem. Since the underlying filesystem stores files as blocks, one Hadoop block may consist of many blocks in the underlying file system. Blocks are large. They default to 64 megabytes each and most systems run with block sizes of 128 megabytes or larger.

Hadoop is designed for streaming or sequential data access rather than random access. Sequential data access means fewer seeks, since Hadoop only seeks to the beginning of each block and begins reading sequentially from there.

A good read is given - [Hadoop sequential data access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942072/hadoop-sequential-data-access)

Comment: I am wondering  the concept "Hadoop is efficient of sequential access", is due to the HDFS block is 64M or larger?

Comment: Hadoop uses blocks to store a file or parts of a file.Hadoop is designed for streaming or sequential data access rather than random access. Sequential data access means fewer seeks, since Hadoop only seeks to the beginning of each block and begins reading sequentially from there.

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop stores files as block (default 128mb) and replicates these blocks on hdd of different nodes.

When you read data from hdd the hdd head has to move across the platter to appropriate locations to read data. If you read many small files spread across the hdd then the seek time for head to move between these location adds significant overhead (reduces throughput).

If you read a single large file head has to seek once and read the data. The total seek time is now less than read time.

This is what is referred as "Hadoop is efficient of sequential access" and it is not so good for random access (with high seek time)

You should not compare hadoop performance with local as hadoop incurs heavy (network) overhead to transfer to/from different nodes over network.

Comment: In my opinion, HDFS is based on local FS(like ext4). A single large file still has to split into several  blocks then stored on nodes. Read the file from hadoop client is not differ with from local system, which need to access inode info and seek block. The access performance  is not optimized?

Comment: Hadoop is designed as a framework and as such independent of OS (or the underlying file system), thus optimization for specific is not possible. Remember Hadoop is a distributed system. To access a file Hadoop client will first query the NameNode for the DataNodes with the files blocks. then query the DataNodes directly for the file blocks. The delay you see is due to the latency of initiating connection between different hosts. The same process on local system is to access the ionode and seek block. Ideally when all latencies are are removed throughput will be similar to local system.